# rosrun/roscd not recognising correct folder/project path

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosrun, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made an executable python script for the nodes, and saved it at the location: /home/florian/catkin_build_ws/src/dlc_project/scripts

1. I have made it executable with chmod +x
2. I have the shebang line on top

But when I type:

```
roscd dlc_project
```

I find myself at : `/home/florian/catkin_build_ws/install/share/dlc_project`, instead of the dlc_project I need (inside ../src/..)
Why does this happen? Any way to change this back to recognise the correct dlc_project folder.

Other details: I use catkin build (instead of catkin_make), Using Python3 + ROS Melodic + Ubuntu 18.04

Thank you!

P.S:

echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/florian/catkin_build_ws/install/share:/home/florian/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/melodic/share

The reason I'm sourcing from /install is because I want to use ROS1+Python3+Cv_bridge and I am following the accepted answer here : [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221565/unable-to-use-cv-bridge-with-ros-kinetic-and-python3?rq=1)

The line: source install/setup.bash --extend,
is probably causing this. But I need to do that so that the Cv bridge built with Python3 is added to the environment. After this, how do I ensure that my project is recognized by ROS as a ROS package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330914/rosrun/roscd-not-recognising-correct-folder/project-path/) by [ambareesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/44870/ambareesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2019-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rmv24](https://answers.ros.org/users/44659/rmv24/) on 2019-08-16**:
Have you sourced your workspace?

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2019-08-16**:
please post the output of `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of sourcing the setup from /install. Source from /devel (source devel/setup.bash). Then roscd should take you to proper directory.

---

Originally posted by [ksb](https://answers.ros.org/users/44805/ksb/) with karma: 36 on 2019-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ambareesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/44870/ambareesh/) on 2019-08-19**:
P.S:

echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH /home/florian/catkin_build_ws/install/share:/home/florian/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/melodic/share

The reason I'm sourcing from /install is because I want to use ROS1+Python3+Cv_bridge and I am following the accepted answer here : SO answer

The line: source install/setup.bash --extend, is probably causing this. But I need to do that so that the Cv bridge built with Python3 is added to the environment. After this, how do I ensure that my project is recognized by ROS as a ROS package?

**Comment by [ksb](https://answers.ros.org/users/44805/ksb/) on 2019-08-21**:
So it is either or case where you can either use the install space or the development space. So as you are using install space, you will end up /home/florian/catkin_build_ws/install/share/dlc_project here after roscd which is not incorrect.
https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/441 This is a link to a similar issue that you can read up.